# Jquery slideshow images very large filesize

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I need a jquery slideshow that fades images when using prev/next buttons. The problem is the images are going to be very high quality 200-300 k in size and there are going to be several. Does anyone know a good way to go about this without causing huge load times?

Many thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the image by Ajax only when the image is requested. This way only the first image is loaded and then each other image is called only when the "Next" button is clicked.

Just google for 'jquery ajax gallery' or something similar.
There are a lot of plugins for this, Just search for the best that fits your needs.

Comment: The downside is that there will be a delay between the button click and the moment when the image will actually be displayed as well as having to re-load an image if the "Previous" button was clicked which would generate unnecessary traffic and overhead.

Comment: True. You can load the first and second image when the page load, then on every click you load the next 2 images. It has his pros and cons, but there is no 'perfect' way to do it. At the and you need to load the image you want to show.

Comment: How do I load images suing AJAX with jquery. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach would be to lazy-preload (don't even know if that's a coined term). Preload the first, say 5 images and append them to the parent slider container, hidden. Then, each time the "Next" button is clicked, preload one more (at this point AJAX might be a convenient way to get the new images), and so on.

By doing it this way, you wouldn't have a lot of preload time and you would also save traffic since your user might not look at all the images. Might not be much, but then again, depending on your website's traffic, it might be something.

**EDIT:**

I think [jQuery Galleria Plugin](http://galleria.aino.se/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.